# How CSRs fit into the SSL Certificate Lifecycle

Tags: ssl

So you decide to go with a CA like VeriSign (or whoever, doesn't matter for this question). You apply for an SSL certificate from them. This CA invesitgates you to make sure the information you provided in your application is truthful and that you are who you say you are. Finally, the CA grants you an SSL certificate.

I am really confused about **CSRs**, what they are, who issues them, who responds to them, and where/how they fit into the scenario described above:

- **Certificate-Signing Request**: To me this means "A request to sign a certificate." So, who makes the request? Who signs it? Why is this necessary?
- When is a CSR generated? When is it acted upon? What subsequent procedures/actions does the CSR hold up (while it is in the process of being signed)?
- How does the CSR fit into the scenario described above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name is confusing - it's not a certificate signing request but a request *for* certificate. When you need to acquire a certificate from the CA, you do the following:

On the client side you generate a keypair (a public and a private key). You save the private key in a safe place, and also you (your generator software) creates a certificate request usually in PKCS#10 format (there's one more format used, which is more rare). This request is a binary ASN.1 sequence of various fields which are filled by you and your software. The request also includes your public key.

Next the certificate request is sent to the CA (usually transmitted over HTTPS). The CA handles the request by parsing it and *creating* a certificate with your public key embodied. Some information provided in the request (mainly your name / organization name, called Subject Name) is copied to the certificate. The certificate is signed with CA's private key.

The procedure can be automated but normally should involve human validation as you will be required to provide identification information (company documents, your documents etc).

Finally you receive a signed certificate from the CA. You can combine it with the private key or you can keep them separated.

Comment: It is not a 'request for certificate'. You already have a certificate. The CSR is a certificate, and it constitutes a 'certificate signing request', and you generate it. Not the CA. All the CA does is sign it, after verifying your identity.

Comment: @EJP please review PKCS#10 format specification. There's no certificate there. Please don't mislead people.